# Как задать разрешение в php?

Tags: php

Я совсем новенький в этом деле, помогите, пожалуйста, задать разрешение сайта.

Comment: Странно это слышать. 
Может имеется ввиду размеры сайта? то это вам в строну CSS нужно.

Comment: Скажите как?

Comment: Советую почитать о [HTML](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml) и [CSS](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss)

Comment: Если надо консультация можете мне написать в скайп: Node_xaker

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Name </title>
<style>
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.main{ width: 95%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='main'>

web site

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Кстати это не php, это технологии HTML + CSS, какие используются в среде php. По умолчанию в html верстки если не указывать точные единицы (пиксели), то сайт растягивается под экран пользователя. Это явление называется "Резиновая верстка".

Answer (score 2):

Что есть разрешение сайта? Ширина в пикселях?

В файле `style.css`, который подключен в `html`-верстку пишем:

```
body{
width: 100%;
}
```